# How did Pauline Phoenix build the interdimensional elevator?

Tags: dead-end

In the TV show *Dead End*, Pauline Phoenix's eponymous park is a magnet for supernatural activity, most of which  seems to come from the interdimensional elevator located in the park, which links to the other twelve planes.

Pauline outright asserts that she built the elevator, although she may have been lying. In any case, she seems to have known something about the supernatural from early on: for instance, in one of her movies she plays the Night Hag, who is revealed to be quite real. She therefore probably at least was involved in the elevator being created. Despite all this, Pauline seems to have been a perfectly normal human actress in life (albeit kind of evil).

How and why did Pauline Phoenix acquire the knowledge or supernatural power to install a connection to other planes in her theme park?